# sum up values of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary such as below:

```
grocery={
    'James': {'Brocolli': 3, 'Carrot': 3, 'Cherry': 5},
    'Jill': {'Apples': 2, 'Carrot': 4, 'Tomatoes': 8},
    'Sunny': {'Apples': 5, 'Carrot': 2, 'Cherry': 2, 'Chicken': 3, 'Tomatoes': 6}
}
food={}
for a,b in grocery.items():
     for i,j in b.items():
          food[i]+=(b.get(i,0))
```

I am trying to calculate total of each food item and it is not working as expected.

For eg: I would like to count total of Carrot, total of Apples and so on.

The above code is giving me following error:

```
File "dictionary1.py", line 6, in <module>
      food[i]+=(b.get(i,0))
   KeyError: 'Cherry
```

How to sum up total of each item?

Comment: You can't use `+=`, you need `food[i] = food.get(i, 0) + j`

Answer (score 2):

Your `food` dictionary is empty and has no keys at the start; you can't just sum up a value to something that isn't there yet.

Instead of `+=`, get the current value *or a default*, using `dict.get()` again:

```
food[i] = food.get(i, 0) + b.get(i,0)
```

You don't really need to use `b.get()` here, as you *already* have the values of `b` in the variable `j`:

```
food[i] = food.get(i, 0) + j
```

You could also use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make keys 'automatically' exist when you try to access them, with a default value:

```
from collections import defaultdict

food = defaultdict(int)  # insert int() == 0 when a key is not there yet
```

and in the inner loop then use `food[i] += j`.

I strongly recommend you use better names for your variables. If you iterate over `dict.values()` rather than `dict.items()`, you can look at the values only when you don't need the keys (like for the outer `for` loop):

```
food = {}
for shopping in grocery.values():
    for name, quantity in shopping.items():
        food[name] = food.get(name, 0) + quantity
```

Another option is to use a dedicated counting and summing dictionary subclass, called [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). This class directly supports summing your groceries in a single line:

```
from collections import Counter

food = sum(map(Counter, grocery.values()), Counter())
```

`map(Counter, ...)` creates `Counter` objects for each of your input dictionaries, and `sum()` adds up all those objects (the extra `Counter()` argument 'primes' the function to use an empty `Counter()` as a starting value rather than an integer `0`).

Demo of the  latter:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sum(map(Counter, grocery.values()), Counter())
Counter({'Tomatoes': 14, 'Carrot': 9, 'Cherry': 7, 'Apples': 7, 'Brocolli': 3, 'Chicken': 3})
```

A `Counter` is still a dictionary, just one with extra functionality. You can always go back to a dictionary by passing the `Counter` to `dict()`:

```
>>> food = sum(map(Counter, grocery.values()), Counter())
>>> dict(food)
{'Brocolli': 3, 'Carrot': 9, 'Cherry': 7, 'Apples': 7, 'Tomatoes': 14, 'Chicken': 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do

`from collections import defaultdict`

`food = defaultdict(int)`  <-- default value of 0 to every non existent key

..and your code should work :)

PS. You get the error because you are trying to add values to uninitialized keys... Don't assume that non existent keys start from 0...

Answer (score 1):

You get the error, because in the beginning the keys, i.e. 'Apples', 'Tomatoes', ..., do not exist in food. You can correct this with a try-except block:

```
grocery={
    "Jill":{"Apples":2, "Tomatoes":8,"Carrot":4},
    "James":{"Carrot":3,"Brocolli":3,"Cherry":5},
    "Sunny":{"Chicken":3,"Apples":5,"Carrot":2,"Tomatoes":6,"Cherry":2}
}
food={}
for a,b in grocery.items():
    for i,j in b.items():
        try:
            food[i] += j
        except KeyError:
            food[i] = j
```

Also, you can get rid of the b.get(i,0) statement, because you already iterate through b and only get values (j) that actually exist in b.